# passing URL parameters using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

how do i use the onclick function when using parameters or is there any other alternative, before i was using anchor links which works but now since i changed it to input type button, instead of just button and using anchor links, it wont work it clicks but not redirecting.

here is an example of my button

```
echo "<input type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='window.location='../../includes/userordersummary.php?orderid=".$row['orderid']."&serial=".$row['serial']."'' value='View Order'>";
```

please note that i am using echo.

Comment: `echo` is not a used in javascript or html. Are you using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1). Escaping**. You need to escape this part:

```
onclick='window.location=\'../../include .... "\'' value='View Order'>";
                         ^--- here              ^-- and here
```

**2).Button styles**. Also

> before i was using anchor links which works but now since i changed it to input type button

you can still use links but make them look like buttons with the same bootstrap classes

```
<a class="btn btn-success">...</a>
```

**3). Confirmation**. If you want to add a confirmation before redirecting you can make use of `confirm` dialog:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="...">click</a>
```

Comment: hmm how do i add a confirmation when for example clicking the button? if i press okay then it would proceed, then if i press no, it would cancel and just refresh the page?